# Does SendGrid provide any such facility which facilitates me with a notification or a flag whenever I Receive an E-mail?

Tags: sendmail, sendgrid

Does SendGrid provide any such facility which facilitates me with a notification or a flag whenever I Receive an E-mail for a specified E-mail address?

I want to know if SendGrid has any such API built in which provides me a notification whenever I receive on my specified email address. ? and if Yes then how to use that ?

If there is any API then i want to integrate it in my C# code. So please help me in that.

Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes - you can use the [SendGrid Inbound API](https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Webhooks/parse.html) to send you webhooks for received email. You can receive and process the webhook in C#.

Answer (score 0):

SendGrid does not handle receipt of email, beyond a very basic HTTP POST Parser.

Comment: is there any other way or API available outside which can provide me the facility for which i am looking ?

I want that whenever i receive an email on say "support@abc.com" it should either send me a notification email or it should set a flag which can further notify or alert me.

thank you